# inject floating button through chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, localhost, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to inject a floating button (found from a tutorial) into a webpage through the means of a chrome extension.
The code runs with no errors but the button is not shown.

**Backgorund script to listen if extension button has been clicked:**

```
// for extention button
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked);

function buttonClicked(tab) {
    
    // Send message to content_script of tab.id
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, 1);
}
```

**Content script to inject code stored on localhost:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);
let injected = false;

function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
     console.log(message);
     if (!injected) {
          injected = true;
          
          var style = document.createElement("link");
          document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
          style.href = "https://localhost/css/test.css";

          var s = document.createElement("script");
          document.body.appendChild(s);
          s.src = "https://localhost/js/test.js";
     }
}
```

I use DOM so I do not have to refresh page to see changes.

**Manifest:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Counterstring",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "simple counterstring generation",
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "matches": [
          "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": ["js/content.js"]
      }
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://localhost/js/test.js; object-src 'self'",
    "background": {
        "persistent": true,
        "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "deafult_icon": "icons/icon16x16.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
         "contextMenus",
         "activeTab"
    ],
    "icons": {
         "16": "icons/icon16x16.png",
         "48": "icons/icon48x48.png",
         "128": "icons/icon128x128.png"
    }
}
```

What follows is the code for the button that is stored on my https://localhost (the code is taken from this tutorial https://www.kirupa.com/html5/drag.htm the only change I made is changing the items from id (#) to class (.)):

**button css:**

```
.beebole_container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      background-color: #333;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 7px;
      touch-action: none;
}
.beebole_item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 230, 99);
    border: 10px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, .5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    touch-action: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.beebole_item:active {
    background-color: rgba(168, 218, 220, 1.00);
}
.beebole_item:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-width: 20px;
}
```

**button js:**

```
window.$b = {
    alert: function(){
        window.alert("1");
    },
    insert_DOM_button: function(){
        let div1 = document.createElement("div");
        let div2 = document.createElement("div");
        let div3 = document.createElement("div");

        div1.className = "outerContainer";
        div2.className = "beebole_container";
        div3.className = "beebole_item";

        div2.appendChild(div3);
        div1.appendChild(div2);
        document.body.appendChild(div1);
    },
    add_button_functionality: function(){
        var dragItem = document.querySelector(".beebole_item");
        var container = document.querySelector(".beebole_container");

        var active = false;
        var currentX;
        var currentY;
        var initialX;
        var initialY;
        var xOffset = 0;
        var yOffset = 0;

        container.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, false);
        container.addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);
        container.addEventListener("touchmove", drag, false);

        container.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
        container.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
        container.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);

        var dragStart = function(e) {
            if (e.type === "touchstart") {
                initialX = e.touches[0].clientX - xOffset;
                initialY = e.touches[0].clientY - yOffset;
            } else {
                initialX = e.clientX - xOffset;
                initialY = e.clientY - yOffset;
            }

            if (e.target === dragItem) {
                active = true;
            }
        }

        var dragEnd = function(e) {
            initialX = currentX;
            initialY = currentY;

            active = false;
        }

        var drag = function(e) {
            if (active) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (e.type === "touchmove") {
                    currentX = e.touches[0].clientX - initialX;
                    currentY = e.touches[0].clientY - initialY;
                } else {
                    currentX = e.clientX - initialX;
                    currentY = e.clientY - initialY;
                }

                xOffset = currentX;
                yOffset = currentY;

                setTranslate(currentX, currentY, dragItem);
            }
        }

        var setTranslate = function(xPos, yPos, el) {
            el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
        }
    }
};

$b.alert();
$b.insert_DOM_button();
$b.add_button_functionality();
```

I am a beginner when it comes to web extensions so please indulge my ignorance.

Have a great day!

Comment: Debug it in devtools debugger and see what fails.

Comment: as far as I can see nothing fails. It just does not show the button. I went through every line with the debugger and everything seems to work fine... If you see in the js of the button there is an alert called which I can see on screen but after that nothing changed. Both css and js are added to the DOM.

Comment: Since it doesn't work then everything's not fine. Did you verify that the script is injected? Does it show the alert? Did you verify the listener is attached on the element (use devtools panel for event listeners or getEventListeners command in console)? Set a breakpoint inside the injected script (or use `debugger` statement) and verify the code actually runs correctly in insert_DOM_button.

Comment: I found the mistake, the problem was that in the tutorial his methods where in global variables. Mine were not so I had to move the instantiation on top of the call. As I said I'm pretty new to all of this. Thx for your help. Would you have any insight on how to make a button that is draggable and "floats" on top of the page itself?

Comment: Sounds like something pretty common to me so there should be examples or libraries for that around.